# Drawing on UIImageView within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, drawing

About my app: The user can view a PDF file within a `UIWebView`. I have an option for the user to choose whether they want to scroll through the pdf or take notes on it. When they take notes, the scrolling is disabled, and vice-versa. However, when the user is drawing, the lines move up and become hazy as shown:
[image: The pic]
(The red boxes are text within the pdf)

Here is my code:

Switching between the pen and scroll:

```
var usingPen = false
@IBAction func usePen(sender: AnyObject) {

    usingPen = true
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
        self.popUpView.alpha = 0
    }

}

@IBAction func useScroll(sender: AnyObject) {

    usingPen = false
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
        self.popUpView.alpha = 0
    }

}
```

The imageView the user draws on (`objectView`):

```
var objectView = UIImageView()
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    objectView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(objectView)

}
```

Drawing on the image view:

```
var start = CGPoint()

let size: CGFloat = 3

var color = UIColor.blackColor()

func draw(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {

    if usingPen == true {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.objectView.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        objectView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: objectView.frame.width, height: objectView.frame.height))
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, size)
        CGContextBeginPath(context)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x, end.y)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        objectView.image = newImage

    }


}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    start = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.objectView))!

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    draw(start, end: (touches.first?.locationInView(self.objectView))!)
    start = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.objectView))!

}
```

How can I prevent the haziness and movement of the drawings? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This probably occurs due to an image scaling issue. Since you're drawing into an image with a scale factor of 1 (which is the default) and your screen has a scale factor of 2 or 3, lines will continue to blur slightly every time they're copied and drawn. The solution is to specify the screen's scale when you create your image context:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.objectView.frame.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
```

Note that the way you're drawing the line is fairly inefficient. Instead, you probably want to create a CGBitmapContext and continually draw to that; it'd be much faster and would also eliminate the "generation loss" problem you have.

Comment: I tried the code you offered; however, when I tried using the pen, the objectView turned black... Do you, by any chance, know why that may occur?

Comment: You could try using `false` instead of `true` in the initialiser (that specifies whether the image is opaque): I used `true` because of performance gains, but since you aren't filling the background colour as white, it probably defaults to black!

Comment: (I changed my answer.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what initializer you are talking about. I also noticed that the objectView doesn't fill the screen anymore. What should I do?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out which initializer you where talking about. However, the drawing still moves up for some reason. How do I solve that problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever figure this out @penatheboss ?

Comment: @CharltonProvatas I came up with a work around: while you're drawing, disable scroll on the scroll view. Then reenable it.

Comment: @penatheboss I just asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005210/free-drawing-on-uiimage-embedded-in-uiscrollview  I will let you know if I can get a more concrete solution.