# Free Drawing On UIImage Embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, core-graphics

I am working on project that involves drawing freehand on a UIImage inside a UIScrollView.  Everything works fine with the drawing at default zoom, however if I adjust the zoom of the UIScrollView and try drawing again, it starts to distort the image by shrinking it and making the image appear blurry.  It also pushes the images to the far left-right of the screen.  I have tried using different scaling options to no avail.

**Here is the image at normal scale with some drawing in it.[image]**

**Here is the image after zooming and drawing for a few seconds**
[image]

**Here is the relevant code (methods are declared in the view controller that contains the scroll view**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)              
    let currentPoint = touches.first!.location(in: drawingImageView) 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingImageView.frame.size, false, 0)
    drawingImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawingImageView.frame.size.width, height: drawingImageView.frame.size.height))

    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.addRect(CGRect(x: currentPoint.x, y: currentPoint.y, width: 1, height: 1))
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setLineCap(.round)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setLineWidth(10)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setStrokeColor(colorSelectorButton.backgroundColor!.cgColor)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setBlendMode(.normal)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.strokePath()
    drawingImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: I ended up refactoring the entire code.  I created a temp UIView on top of the imageView that handles all the drawing in the drawRect method of the uiview.  Then when the drawing is finished, I rendered an uiimage out of the view and merged it with the below image.  This refactor still however does not solve the original issue, and this refactored way makes any image-erasing functionality much more challenging to implement.